# carouFredSel slide auto run items trouble

Tags: jquery

I just have a question , how can i make carouFredSel auto run only if i have more than 3 items?I set items: 3;but it's still auto run even it had only 2 items inside.
Here is my jquery:

```
jQuery(".big-gallery > .gallery").carouFredSel({
        auto: true,
        items: 3,
        direction: "up",
        infinite: false,
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 1e3,
            pauseDuration: 3e3,
            pauseOnHover: "immediate"
        }
    })
```

Tks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your logic, You can set auto false if there are less items like,

```
var autoScroll=jQuery(".big-gallery > .gallery").length>3; // true only if items are more than 3
jQuery(".big-gallery > .gallery").carouFredSel({
    auto: autoScroll,// add this autoscroll here
    items: 3,
    direction: "up",
    infinite: false,
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        duration: 1e3,
        pauseDuration: 3e3,
        pauseOnHover: "immediate"
    }
});
```